# Segregate or devide the values and make pie charts based on them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I have some data fetching from backend database server, which is returning the below details.

```
[{ "Year": 2014, "Name": "A", "Values": 18 },{ "Year": 2014, "Name": "B", "Values": 16 },{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "D", "Values": 20},{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "C", "Values": 0 },{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "A", "Values": 0 },{ "Year": 2016, "Name": "D", "Values": 19 }]
```

but what I want is that first divide / group the arrays based on the year in each separate array or list of array based on the length, then want to use them for pie chart. Can someone help me here.

Comment: Please post how do you like looks the groups.

Comment: **Alexandru-lonut**, the groups should be based on Year like all names and values for 2014 year as one entity for pie chart, that pie chart should display all the names and values for 2014 year and it is same for other years, means there should be 10 pie charts created dynamically based on different years(10 nos).

Comment: I posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution. First of all, you need to create a `years` array without duplicates.Suppose that we have `n` years. Then, you need to create data array for each of `n` years. Further more, it should create `n` divs where charts will be draw.

```js
var json=[{ "Year": 2014, "Name": "A", "Values": 18 },{ "Year": 2014, "Name": "B", "Values": 16 },{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "D", "Values": 20},{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "C", "Values": 0 },{ "Year": 2015, "Name": "A", "Values": 0 },{ "Year": 2016, "Name": "D", "Values": 19 }];

var years=[];
json.forEach(function(obj){
  if(years.indexOf(obj.Year)==-1)
    years.push(obj.Year);
});

for(i=0;i<years.length;i++){
    data=[['Task','Years']];
    json.forEach(function(obj){
        if(obj.Year==years[i]){
           data.push([obj.Name,obj.Values]);
        }
    });
     var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
     elemDiv.style.width="900px";
     elemDiv.style.height="500px";
     elemDiv.id="piechart"+i;
     document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
    displayChart(data,i);
}
function displayChart(dataForChart,i){
     var chartData=dataForChart;
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
          var options = {
              title: years[i]
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'+i));
 
         chart.draw(data, options);
      }
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

If you are using `AngularJS` you need something like this:

```
var years=[];
json.forEach(function(obj){
  if(years.indexOf(obj.Year)==-1)
    years.push(obj.Year);
});
$scope.years=years;
```

And in HTML you need to create `n` divs like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" id="piechart{{$index+1}}">
     //chart will be draw here
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly make this solution either in angularjs or just javascript, because I am not using jQuery in my project.

Comment: Your solution seems to be great, but let me tell you one more thing that I already have a chart(different one) and I want to display your above charts beneath the exist one, but its not appearing, bcoz of no div element available inside the html directly. So can you tell me how do I place this there. and I am using angularjs!.

Comment: @Saleem, please see now at the end of post.

Comment: **Alexandru**, I see blank are only. in HTML I see this in page inspector **<div ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" id="piechart1" class="ng-scope">     </div>** only. Below is the html code in my file. **<div layout="row" flex="100" class="myforms" style="border: 1px solid orange; padding: 10px;">
       <div id="chart_div2" style="width:1000px; height:500px;"></div>
</div>
    <div layout="row" flex="100" class="myforms" style="border: 1px solid orange; padding: 10px;">
        <div ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" id="piechart{{$index+1}}">
        </div>
    </div>**

Comment: Yes..this creates those 3 div where chart will be drawn.Is that you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129941/discussion-between-saleem-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).

Comment: **Alexandru**, your code which we setup, just repeating the piechart with the same data, its not taking the next year's data.

Comment: **Alexandru**, and more importantly its not printing n number of charts, instead printing only two fixed pie.

Comment: But if you display {{year}} it works ? (I mean it is displaying all years? )

Comment: **Alexandru**, thanks but I just figured it out, there was a mistake in yesterday's code with the ng-repeat and myFunction. Now its working quite fine. instead of passing index+1 we just have to pass index which starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Charts, see the snippet bellow (it causes a cross origin error, but it's because of the google loader, it should still work, just expand the snippet), or at least use it as example for other pie chart implementations:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  var dbData = [{
   "Year": 2014,
   "Name": "A",
   "Values": 18
  }, {
   "Year": 2014,
   "Name": "B",
   "Values": 16
  }, {
   "Year": 2015,
   "Name": "D",
   "Values": 20
  }, {
   "Year": 2015,
   "Name": "C",
   "Values": 0
  }, {
   "Year": 2015,
   "Name": "A",
   "Values": 0
  }, {
   "Year": 2016,
   "Name": "D",
   "Values": 19
  }];

  var yearFieldName = "Year";
  var nameFieldName = "Name";
  var valuesFieldName = "Values";


  function createPieChartData(data, keyTitle, valueTitle) {
   var yearGroups = {};
   var result = [];
   result.push([keyTitle, valueTitle]);

   var year = null;
   //summing values of records in each year grouped by year ()
   for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    year = data[i][yearFieldName];
    if (typeof year === "number" || typeof year === "string") {
     if (typeof yearGroups[year] === "undefined") {
      yearGroups[year + ""] = 0;
     }

     yearGroups[year] += data[i][valuesFieldName];
    } else {
     //do whatever here, for example:
     //throw new Error("some bad data type of 'Year' field passed from DB");
    }
   }

   for(var y in yearGroups) {
    result.push([y, yearGroups[y]]);
   }

   return result;
  }

  function drawChart() {

   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(createPieChartData(dbData, "Year", "Sum of Values"));

   var options = {
     title: 'Values for each year:'
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not what I am looking for, I want to design/create saperate pie chart for each year, it means each year is will act as a saperate group and then there should be saperate piechart. like for 2014 there should be one pie chart and for 2015 there should be one and so on...the data will be fetch dynamically from database server and the charts should be created dynamically using something like for loop.